# advanced if else javascript statement use in code protection

Tags: javascript, optimization, if-statement

I have a question, not about the JS code obfuscation ( it's not really the subject), but for understand a JS if else notation.

When we use obfuscation tools on JS code, the generated code contains a statement like this :

```
(0xA6, 78.) <= 0x204 ? val : otherVal
```

I know the if Else statement and the reduce version.
in this exemple the obfuscate tool use numbers with other hex base ( ok for this )

But the notation :

```
( value , other value )
```

Why this and for make what ?

Thanks for your help to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the comma separated list is only evaluating the most outer right value, in this case the number `78`. It could also look like

```
(0xA6, 42, 11, 78.)
```

and it would still evaluate to `78` (the decimal point at the end ist just optional). The second number is only the octal version of the number `516`. So in reality the line is

```
78 < 516 ? val : otherVal
```

which is a pretty simple condition written with a ternary operator, it could also be written like

```
if( 78 < 516 ) {
    // assign val somewhere
} else {
    // assign otherVal somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a comma operator:

[The javascript comma operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

[Mozilla Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)